# JSF page redirecting from java bean

Tags: jsf, redirect, managed-bean

Is there some way how to **redirect** page to other page from Java method?

I'm able only to **forward** it using:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/foo.xhtml");
```

or using navigation-rules of `faces-config.xml`.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What sort of "easy" way are you thinking of?

Comment: I don´t know:) Actually I need any way

Comment: Well, you've already mentioned the navigation-rules method. Another is to send a Javascript snippet from Java telling the browser to navigate (`document.location.href="someplace"`). You can send a snippet using `JavscriptContext.addJavascriptCall(..., ...)` but it's a lousy method :)

Comment: Oh, thank you, but for now I hope some easier method exists (i know almost nothing about javascript :-)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Not sure what you're after, but the `ExternalContext#dispatch()` does only a forward, not a redirect. You'd like to use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
externalContext.redirect("foo.xhtml");
```

or even external (which is not possible with dispatch)

```
externalContext.redirect("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

You'd normally like to do this in bean's action method.

---

Since you mentioned JavaScript in the comments, here's how you could redirect using JS:

```
window.location = "foo.xhtml";
// Or
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC, that's answer to the question how to redirect page from java bean. And rest of my answer (any to any) is bullshit :)

Comment: I've learned more about JSF from @BalusC than from any other source.  Thanks for sharing, man.  I owe you a beer if we ever run in to each other.

Comment: Is the URL you're redirecting to relative to the context path or to the path of the bean's calling facelet?

Comment: @Wecherowski Relativity doesn't change the subject. The new URL is just relative to current URL not to path or package or bean or whatever doesn't represent the current URL. You may find this related Q&A more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30683584

Answer (score 2):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "page.xhtml");
```

Works just as well.

Comment: It might but it is overly complicated and not needed

Comment: I actually like this answer as this allows a redirect from inside a ``preRenderView`` to another facelet by its pretty faces ID.

Answer (score -2):

please try with the call to the following static function:

```
String url = "/meta/default/inbox"; // Your URL here

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

Comment: Couple of things...1: The spaces in your code make it fail, 2: it is 'identical' with what is done in the lots of upvoted answer with a very small difference, the external context is assigned to a variable there. Hence all the downvotes I think. Better to remove the question. Cheers