# Redirecting parent/top level from inner iframe through bean

Tags: jsf, redirect, iframe, jsf-2

I would like to be able to redirect a top level/parent xhtml through a bean. I have tried the following within my bean class:

```
if (result == 1) {
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "You have successfully changed your password. Please log in to continue.", null));
  con.close();
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
  return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

also

```
if (result == 1) {
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "You have successfully changed your password. Please log in to continue.", null));
  con.close();
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().redirect("/index.xhtml");
  return;
}
```

Both of the above will redirect the iframes page but not the parent page. How would I achieve this?

The following are other pages I have referenced with no luck:

- [JSF page redirecting from java bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955130/jsf-page-redirecting-from-java-bean)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837614/how-to-redirect-jsf-page-from-iframe-to-parent-window
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072739/redirecting-iframes-parent-page-using-ajax-and-jsf