# What URL to use to link / navigate to other JSF pages

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-2, hyperlink, navigation

I am confused about how to link between files in a Java Server Faces project, when some of the files are in sub-folders. (I was going to attach screenshots so you can see the Nebeans project view, and files view of the example I am trying.... but I'm not allowed to add images yet).

I my example project I have files called "index.xhtml" and "calculate/calculate.xhtml".  I also have a file called "template.xhtml" which is used by both.  The question is what url format to use in the template that will work for both files.

In straight html I would just use something like the following to provide a link back to the home page that would work from any location:

```
<a href="/index.html">Home</a>
```

But I can't figure out what counts as the root folder for a JSF application, and whether to use the "project view" folder structure or the "files list" folder structure.

Comment: Template files are merely to be included on the server-end by means of `<ui:include src="...">` in combination with `<ui:insert name="...">`. It makes no difference in the target URL by which a client may request the resource associated with that URL. What difference do you observe when moving to JSF?

Comment: In my template, if I use the following line:

Comment: In my template, if I use `<a href="/index.xhtml" ..` then glassfish server thinks it is `http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml`.  However, if I use `<a href="index.xhtml" ..` then the index file is expected to be in the same folder as the xhtml file ...so I'm confused what to do

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, JSF is a HTML code generator. So it's not different in JSF than in "plain" HTML. You should just not look at file system structure in webapp project when creating links in HTML. You should look at public URL structure of those resources. It's namely the webbrowser who has got to invoke and download those resources, not the webserver. The webbrowser knows absolutely nothing about the file system structure in the webserver. This is not specific to JSF projects. This applies to all web projects.

Relative URLs are not relative to their location in the file system structure in webapp project. They are relative to the request URL of the currently opened HTML document, exactly the one you see in browser's address bar. Noted should be that when a `<base>` element is present in the HTML document, then all relative URLs in the HTML document not starting with `/` will become relative to it.

Given a webapp which is configured with `FacesServlet` mapping URL pattern of `*.xhtml`, and is deployed to `localhost:8080` with a context path of `/context`, the URL of a `/index.xhtml` file in project's web root will be as below:

```
http://localhost:8080/context/index.xhtml
----   -------------- ------- -----------
  |           |          |         `-- resource
  |           |          `-- path (can be multiple folders)
  |           `-- domain (and port)
  `-- scheme
```

When you're currently in `http://localhost:8080/context/index.xhtml`, and you want to create a link to `http://localhost:8080/context/calculate/calculate.xhtml`, then all the ways below will ultimately point to exactly the same absolute URL.

- A relative URL starting with `//` is relative to the current scheme.

  ```
  <a href="//localhost:8080/context/calculate/calculate.xhtml">link</a>
  ```
- A relative URL starting with `/` is relative to the domain.

  ```
  <a href="/context/calculate/calculate.xhtml">link</a>
  ```
- A relative URL *not* starting with `/` is relative to the path.

  ```
  <a href="calculate/calculate.xhtml">link</a>
  ```

And when you're currently in 
`http://localhost:8080/context/calculate/calculate.xhtml`, and you want to link to `http://localhost:8080/context/index.xhtml`, then the same rules apply:

- A relative URL starting with `//` is relative to the current scheme.

  ```
  <a href="//localhost:8080/context/index.xhtml">link</a>
  ```
- A relative URL starting with `/` is relative to the domain.

  ```
  <a href="/context/index.xhtml">link</a>
  ```
- A relative URL *not* starting with `/` is relative to the path.

  ```
  <a href="../index.xhtml">link</a>
  ```

As you probably realize by now, a relative URL starting with `/` is **not** dependent from the current path and domain. So, that's the URL you really want to use everywhere in your web application without worrying about maintenance trouble when changing domain or moving around files in the server. The only thing left is the dynamicness of the context path. You probably already know that this value is not controllable from inside the webapp. You'd really like to avoid hardcoding it. You can however easily let JSF print it programmatically with a little help of EL. It's namely just available by [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) and the `HttpServletRequest` is in EL available as implicit object `#{request}`.

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml">link</a>
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/calculate/calculate.xhtml">link</a>
```

It only gets tedious to repeat this everytime. Fortunately, JSF offers the [`<h:link>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/link.html) component for the very purpose of generating a HTML `<a>` element with the current context path automatically inlined.

```
<h:link value="link" outcome="index.xhtml" />
<h:link value="link" outcome="calculate/calculate.xhtml" />
```

Note that the `outcome` must represent a JSF view ID, which is not necessarily the same as the URL path (it will be when you map `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`). You can even omit the file extension here, JSF will automatically detect it as part of "implicit navigation" mechanism.

```
<h:link value="link" outcome="index" />
<h:link value="link" outcome="calculate/calculate" />
```

#### See also:

- [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)
- [What are those URL's that are starting with // - that you can see within Google+ html source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656315/what-are-those-urls-that-are-starting-with-that-you-can-see-within-google/)
- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [Implicit objects in EL](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)

Comment: Great answer, thanks!
I couldn't find a decent description of all that anywhere. If there is a concise documentation resource I'm missing, please let me know.
I'm working through _The Java EE 7 Tutorial: Volume 1: Basic Concepts (Java Series)_ but they didn't cover that yet, and none of their examples have xhtml files in sub-folders.
I did actually try `href="#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml"` before didn't really understand what it was doing, and I guess something else was wrong at that time.
Anyway it's working now, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not exactly JSF. It's just HTTP and HTML. Knowing HTTP and HTML is indeed a prerequisite before diving into JSF. Learning JSF is in this specific case knowing the purpose of `<h:link>` and `#{request.contextPath}` (although the latter is more Servlet+EL specific than JSF specific).