# Get the web application context path from META-INF/context.xml to produce an outcome for navigating

Tags: tomcat, jsf, primefaces, contextpath

I have a primefaces web application running on tomcat 8. In `META-INF/context.xml` I defined the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/syslac"/>
```

While in my view xhtml page I have this fragment code  where p:commandButton has a oncomplete tag that will execute the handleLoginRequest function.

```
<h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
               <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Usuario:" />
               <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.usuarioVendedor.usuarioSistema}" id="username" required="true" label="username" />
               <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Contrasena:" />
               <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.usuarioVendedor.clave}" id="password" required="true" label="password" />
               <f:facet name="footer">
                  <p:commandButton value="Ingresar" update=":growl" actionListener="#{loginBean.loguearse}" oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
               </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
         </h:form>
```

The script:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) 
{
                if (args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {
                    jQuery('#dialog').effect("shake", {times: 2}, 100);
                } else {
                    dlg.hide();
                    jQuery('#loginLink').fadeOut();
                    window.location = args.view;
                }
}
</script>
```

But I can not retrieve the context path from `META-INF/context.xml` through logginBean so that I can send view arg to be used by window.location in navigation: `/syslac/page.xhtml` where syslac is context path of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context path is in backing bean available by [`ExternalContext#getRequestContextPath()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestContextPath--).

```
String contextPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
```

So you could do for example:

```
String loginURI = contextPath + "/login.xhtml";
// ...
```

Note that this is completely unnecessary when using as JSF navigation outcome. For the correct approach, see the second "See also" link in bottom.

The context path is available in EL by [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath--).

```
#{request.contextPath}
```

So you could do for example:

```
<h:outputScript>
    // ...
    window.location = "#{request.contextPath}" + args.view;
</h:outputScript>
```

Or when your script is in a `.js` file (correct practice!):

```
<html lang="en" data-baseuri="#{request.contextPath}">
```

```
window.location = document.documentElement.dataset.baseuri + args.view;
```

#### See also:

- [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url)
- [What URL to use to link / navigate to other JSF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683584/what-url-to-use-to-link-navigate-to-other-jsf-pages)