# Is it possible to get the root-context (defined on the web.xml) of an application

Tags: jsf, web.xml

Example of root-context

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-web>
        <context-root>/Tesoreria-WEB</context-root>
        <max-active-sessions>300</max-active-sessions>
    </jboss-web>
```

Is it possible to get that "/TESORERIA-WEB" with some method in java with primefaces?

I have tried

```
PrimeRequestContext.getCurrentInstance(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getApplicationContext());
```

But no success and can't find something on the internet about specifically getting root-context from web.xml

Comment: This answer from @BalusC is what worked for me, thank you guys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556861/get-the-web-application-context-path-from-meta-inf-context-xml-to-produce-an-out  so its basically FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();  to get that "/Tesoreria-WEB"

Answer (score 0):

**[`servletContext.getContextPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath())**

> Returns the context path of the web application.
>
> The context path is the portion of the request URI that is used to select the context of the request. The context path always comes first in a request URI. The path starts with a `/` character but does not end with a `/` character. For servlets in the default (root) context, this method returns "".*

or

**[`httpServletRequest.getContextPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath())**

> Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request. The context path always comes first in a request URI. The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/" character. For servlets in the default (root) context, this method returns "". The container does not decode this string.

Comment: For such basic jsf things duplicates exist and even for plain servlet like your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675730/finding-your-applications-url-with-only-a-servletcontext

Comment: Nothing for context-root?