# Unable to link pages using JSF

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

Basically I access `LancarAutorizacaoFaturamento.xhtml` which includes `PainelFinanceiro.xhtml` and form there I would like to have a link to `cadastroConta.xhtml` passing a GET parameter. However; it just won't work, when the page renders, that link has the following message: `"This link is disabled because a navigation case can't be found."`

Here is what I've tried:

```
<h:link value="#{painel.strContaAssociada}" outcome="../conta/cadastroConta">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{painel.getId()}" />
</h:link>
```

Here are my past outcome tries:

```
protected/financeiro/conta/cadastroConta.xhtml
/protected/financeiro/conta/cadastroConta.xhtml
../protected/financeiro/conta/cadastroConta.xhtml
../../financeiro/conta/cadastroConta.xhtml
../../financeiro/conta/cadastroConta
../financeiro/conta/cadastroConta.xhtml
../financeiro/conta/cadastroConta
/financeiro/conta/cadastroConta.xhtml
../conta/cadastroConta.xhtml
../conta/cadastroConta
/conta/cadastroConta
conta/cadastroConta
cadastroConta
```

This seems like a simple task, what am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: When you manually open the cadastroConta.xhtml page, what exactly is the URL which you see in webbrowser's address bar? That is the URL you ultimately want to map in the outcome. See also  https://stackoverflow.com/q/30683584/

Comment: Hi BalusC, this is the complete URL of cadastroConta.xhtml: `http://localhost:8080/evop/protected/financeiro/conta/cadastroConta.xhtml`

Comment: Then you should be able to use `outcome="protected/financeiro/conta/cadastroConta"` (as explained in the link in the previous comment). Is this true? It should also keep working if you add the `/` prefix and/or the `.xhtml` suffix. If this is however not true, then that's probably a bug in the JSF impl being used or a misconfiguration in the JSF mapping. You'd better tell JSF impl/version being used and how exactly you've mapped the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with the ´/´ prefix, but not without it. None the less it worked using ´/´ as the prefix. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it? By the way, just bought your book last week!

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe: Please do like BalusC requested and add your JSF version and implementation... Always do this when asking jsf question (or for any other framework)